# Print commerce pricing attributes to email receipt

Tags: 7, views, commerce, emails, tokens

Users cannot see what size or color shirt they purchased in the email receipt because tokens won't print the attribute fields provided by [Commerce Product Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) / [Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes) / [Commerce Product Option](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option) combo.

1. User selects shirt size: XL and color: Green
2. Both fields can be previewed during checkout.
3. Email receipt received doesn't show any attributes, user cannot check what size/color they ordered.
   (All this can be achieved using default CCK fields under product type, but we're using the combination mentioned above for multiple reasons, many products got different option sets to chose from and certain attributes selected adds extra price to total, like eg size: XXXL costs extra $3+ and this cannot be achieved with default fields).

One of the tokens I found is like eg. `[commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0:commerce-pricing-attributes]` and email on checkout prints it like this:

```
Product: BK Test

a:1:{s:9:"coveralls";a:8:{s:25:"field_coverall_embroidery";N;s:25:"field_coverall_text_color";N;s:10:"field_font";N;s:16:"field_shirt_name";N;s:16:"field_patch_side";N;s:12:"field_length";s:1:"2";s:21:"field_coveralls_color";s:1:"4";s:19:"field_coverall_size";s:2:"16";}}
```

Also more tokens available at `admin/help/token` like eg.: `Attributes  [commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field_attributes]  Pricing Attributes field.` and combining them with `[commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0:commerce-product]` won't work, already tried dozens of variations.

E.g. in Order's view page I addded the view `Commerce Line Item: Product Attributes` and it displays correctly.

[image]

How to print this in the email receipt?

Comment: Have you tried write your own token or write a custom function with order parameter?

Comment: It's easy using entity_metadata_wrapper to find what you want and print it.

Comment: Well,  all the tokens already exist in the token help list for each and every field,  they just won't print if it's order/line item.

Comment: i think can you use hook_tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install [views rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules), make a views-rules of orders, you will need OID as a contextual filter, add it as allways, then in middle column, in parameters settings set your OID as:integer, add all fields/attributes you wish, now in middle column settings, set your fields/attributes values as text, choose 'use rendered output'.

Then in your send-email-to-customer rule, add a views-rule with your new view, actions: fecth entity by id:ORDER with your variable OID, now you have all fields/attributes you added avilable as tokens, built your email body like: thanks [user:name], your order [OID] is in proccess, you bought : T-shirt [tshirt:value],  T-shirt-size: [tshirt-size:value], ............. .

if you can not use HTML tags, here is an exported rules_action_info() rules code that i used in one site, adds a new action: build-email-body, it shows you how to built a row for a 'nice'
html look alike. if you need this feature, you will need to make a custom module called: rulesbodyemail, change all $variables and code as needed, take a close look how is built variable:  $text_formatted_body, and is how is returned.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implement hook_rules_action_info()
 * Declare any meta data about actions for Rules
 */

 function rulesbodyemail_rules_action_info() {


 $actions = array(
'buitl_email_body' => array(
    'label' => t('build-email-body'),
    'group' => t('cadena'),

    'parameter' => array(

      'node_id' => array(
              'type' => 'integer',
              'label' => t('node id'),
              ),

      'parcialidad_title' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('parcialidad_title'),
              ),

      'parcialidad_monto' => array(
              'type' => 'decimal',
              'label' => t('parcialidad monto'),
              ),
      'parcialidad_cliente' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('cliente'),
              ),

      'parcialidad_fecha' => array(
              'type' => 'date',
              'label' => t('parcialidad fecha'),
              ),
      'parcialidad_aseguradora' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('cia aseguradora'),
              ),

      'parcialidad_ramo' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('ramo'),
              ),

        'parcialidad_cobertura' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => t('cobertura'),
                ),

        'parcialidad_fecha_formateada' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => t('feha formateada'),
                ),

          ),


    'provides' => array(
        'text_formatted_body' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => t('text_formatted body'),
                'wrap' => TRUE,
                //'format' => 'full_html'
                ),
              ),
  ),
);
  return $actions;

 } // fin de actions_info

// rules function procesar row
function buitl_email_body($node_id, $parcialidad_title, $parcialidad_monto,
$parcialidad_cliente, $parcialidad_fecha, $parcialidad_aseguradora,
$parcialidad_ramo, $parcialidad_cobertura, $parcialidad_fecha_formateada) {

// variable $hoy esta en UNIX
$hoy = time();
$formatted_hoy = date('j/M/y', $hoy);

  //drupal_set_message($parcialidad_fecha_int . ' $parcialidad_fecha ', 'status', FALSE);
  //drupal_set_message($formatted_fecha . ' $formatted_fecha ', 'status', FALSE);

  //prepara las variables y calcula dias vencidos
  $parcialidad_fecha_int = strip_tags($parcialidad_fecha);
  $hoy_int = (int)$hoy;
  $fecha_int = (int)$parcialidad_fecha_int;
  $diff = $hoy_int - $fecha_int;
  $diff = round($diff/86400);

  // formato fecha y $ pesos

  $monto_format = "$".number_format($parcialidad_monto, 2);
  $formatted_fecha = date('j/M/y', $parcialidad_fecha_int);

  //hace el render del row
  $text_formatted_body =
  "
  ▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁

  ▲ PARCIALIDAD ▲ $parcialidad_cliente

    Parcialidad: $parcialidad_title
    Monto:  $monto_format
    Venció: $formatted_fecha; Días vencidos: $diff

    Aseguradora : $parcialidad_aseguradora
    Ramo: $parcialidad_ramo; Cobertura: $parcialidad_cobertura

  " ;

  //return $text_formatted_body
  return array('text_formatted_body' => $text_formatted_body);



  } // fin de funcion rules procesar row
```

it returns this as the email body:

[image]

image of rule to send emails:

[image]

image of body email value

[image]

Comment: Insane solution, holy moly, can't believe this works, this Views Rules module is really powerful and it's not updated since 2k12! And for formatting, I didn't need custom module, just add internal `<style></style>` at the top of the body above all the tokens in the rules. Thanks for helping.

Comment: hi @pinueve, it sends separate email for each line item in the cart. So if ordering 5 items, user gets 5 emails with each product. Should be all products in one email. Can you make a screenshot of your rules setup?

Comment: it could be that your rules-view is returning same order several times, in query settings toggle 'unique results', or in rule-email do send email outside the views-loop, to do this, add a text-token variable first and outside views-loop, built body as you did, and asign your text-token-variable with email-body value, and send email with variable-token, let me know if this helps.

Comment: i added images of my rule and email body value.

Comment: Here's mine https://i.imgur.com/apQ5IUx.png everything you move outside loop does not get picked up, no tokens available and email is empty. I do not see the fetch ID part in your screenshot and seem like yours using author ID and not order ID and you have multiple data fields. I ticked the disctinct in the view, but I don't think it's the problem, the emails are not dupes, it sends separate email for separate line item in the order with its details.

Comment: here is my complete COMPONENT, i did component because my emails are send everyday scheduleded, i pull UID's from a node-view with aggregations, this you don't need that,     https://imgur.com/rhfZj73
https://imgur.com/c6n1LDB
https://imgur.com/ex9zuiy

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258194/how-to-create-a-rule-to-email-all-users-with-a-profile-field-x-with-same-value-a/258195#258195

Comment: The `products_attribute` that is pulled by views rules cannot be before the loop in the variable action with the rest off the email body. Email won't print the field. Email won't print anything that's outside the loop. And if it's inside, you get separate emails for each line item. Eg this is the only order I get to work: https://i.imgur.com/icgVkre.png

Comment: more hints: set in your views-rule to show only one row; check that your email should be sent in 'check-out-proccess'; play with rules-conditional-module, it adds new conditionals inside actions.

Comment: I don't see where to set to show one row, my field doesn't have that, unless you meant pager. It's set to checkout process. Here's a gif of my view: https://i.imgur.com/k5vW41a.gifv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88588/discussion-between-pinueve-and-user3108268).

Comment: HI, could you ponit me wich module you are using to provode full HTML emial-body, and please share your email-body <style> tags

Comment: mailsystem with mimemail and CSS is just font size and colors, you can put anything (I get field classes by exporting the email as .html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function mymodule_token_info(){
    $info['tokens']['commerce-order']['line_item_detail'] = array(
        'name' => t('Line Item Product Detail List'),
        'description' => t('List all the Product Line Item Detail of the order')
    );
    return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

  if($type == 'commerce-order'){
    $order = $data['commerce-order'];
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order',$order);
    $lineItems = $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items->value();
    $lineItemArray = array();
    foreach($lineItems as $key => $value){
        $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item',$value);
        if($line_item_wrapper->type->value()=='product'){
            $product_title = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->title->value();
            $quantity = $line_item_wrapper->quantity->value();
            $lineItemArray[] =  $product_title.' x '.$quantity;
        }
    }

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'line_item_detail':
            $variables = array(
                'items' => $lineItemArray,
                'type' => 'ul',
            );
            $replacements[$original] = theme('item_list', $variables);
            break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```

This is the sample code.

You can modify the result you want at hook_tokens().

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this shows only title and quantity. I tried adding `product_attributes` or simple `sku` I get error `Unable to get a data value. Error: Unknown data property sku.`

Comment: I was missing `->commerce_product->` for SKU to be printed, but still can't figure how to print product attributes like in the given screenshot.

Comment: `product_attributes` (seen in screenshot, displays correct via views) gives error mentioned before and field `field_custom_attributes` that is Pricing Attributes field type prints `Array` and notice `Array to string conversion line 30`

Comment: you can use follow this https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers, and then you can get what you want.
you can use $wrapper->commerce_price->amount->value(), and change amount to decimal by using commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($amount,$currency);